# Office.context.mailbox.item.loadCustomPropertiesAsync fails in Shared Mailbox on New Outlook for Mac

Tags: office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

Here's the sample Script Lab code to reproduce the issue:

```
function run() {
  const item = Office.context.mailbox.item;

  item.loadCustomPropertiesAsync(result => {
    console.log(result)
  })
}
```

The output of the above code will always be as follows:

```
value: undefined
status: "failed"
error: {
    name: "AccessRestricted"
    message: "Internal protocol error: '-2147467259'."
    code: 9017
}
```

This issue was reproduced on:

- New Outlook for Mac v16.52 (21080801)
- macOS Big Sur 11.5.1

Comment: I'd also recommend posting a bug report to the `OfficeJS` repo in GitHub.

Comment: We are unable to reproduce this issue. Could you please check the delegate permissions with the below code

Office.context.mailbox.item.getSharedPropertiesAsync((result) => console.log(JSON.stringify(result)));

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT Here's the output: `{"value":{"delegatePermissions":63,"owner":"examplesharedmailbox@domain.com","targetRestUrl":"https://outlook.office.com/api","targetMailbox":"examplesharedmailbox@domain.com"},"status":"succeeded"} `

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT This is only happening on New Outlook for Mac

Comment: We are not able to repro the issue at our end. We would like to collect the logs to understand the issue more. Follow these steps to get us the incident ID:
1. Repro the issue
2. Click on Help tab from Outlook Menu
3. Click on collect Diagnostics
4. This will generate an Incident ID, share that with us.

Also some more questions which we have:
1. Is this issue occurring on Read or Compose mode
2. If OP is doing some specific steps before calling the API in which case, the issue repros or does API fail consistently.